# Earliest method to use IBInspectable values?

Tags: swift

I have multiple IBInspectables and currently I am retrieving the values that have been set in the interface builder in overriding `layoutSubviews`. Is there an earlier way to retrieve the values? In awakeFromNib the values are not available, and I do not want to use didSet.

Comment: Why do you want it earlier?

Comment: `IBInspectable`s should be set before you receive `awakeFromNib`. If they're not, that's a bug in Apple's framework.